# protocol buffer GetRepeatedField (reflection) code optimization

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, protocol-buffers

I'm using the reflection feature of protocol buffer to read message field value at run time.

The proto I have:

```
package xapp.battle;
    message BATTLE_DATA {
        repeated AInfo aInfo = 1;
        repeated BInfo bInfo = 2;
        repeated CInfo cInfo = 3;
        // a lot other repeated messages
    }

    message AInfo {
        int32 test_field = 1;
        // ......
    }

    message BInfo {
        int32 test_field = 1;
        // ......
    }

    message CInfo {
        int32 test_field = 1;
        // ......
    }
```

The code now I have:

```
void DO_SOMETHING(messageName) {

    const Descriptor* pDescriptor = BATTLE_DATA->GetDescriptor();
    const FieldDescriptor* pMessageField = pDescriptor->FindFieldByName(messageName);
    const Reflection* pReflection = BATTLE_DATA->GetReflection();

    if (messageName == "aInfo") {
        const RepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::AInfo> repeated_ptr_field = pReflection->GetRepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::AInfo>(*BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeated_ptr_field.size(); i ++) {
            ::xapp::battle::AInfo messageInfo = repeated_ptr_field.Get(i);
            // continue to read the test_field value of messageInfo
        }
    }
    else if (messageName == "bInfo") {
        const RepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::BInfo> repeated_ptr_field = pReflection->GetRepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::BInfo>(*BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeated_ptr_field.size(); i ++) {
            ::xapp::battle::BInfo messageInfo = repeated_ptr_field.Get(i);
            // continue to read the test_field value of messageInfo
        }
    }
    else if (messageName == "CInfo") {
        const RepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::CInfo> repeated_ptr_field = pReflection->GetRepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::CInfo>(*BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeated_ptr_field.size(); i ++) {
            ::xapp::battle::CInfo messageInfo = repeated_ptr_field.Get(i);
            // continue to read the test_field value of messageInfo
        }
    }
    // ......
    else {
            LOG("loadOneBin - Unknown messageName");
    }
}
```

This code works but obviously it's not the best solution since there are so many repeated "else-if" code blocks.

What I want is something like (at least get rid of those "else-if" blocks):

```
const RepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::MESSAGE_NAME> repeated_ptr_field = pReflection->GetRepeatedPtrField<::xapp::battle::MESSAGE_NAME>(*BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField);
for (int i = 0; i < repeated_ptr_field.size(); i ++) {
    ::xapp::battle::MESSAGE_NAME messageInfo = repeated_ptr_field.Get(i);
    // continue to read the test_field value of messageInfo

}
```

The source code of GetRepeatedPtrField:

```
template<typename PB>
inline const RepeatedPtrField<PB>& Reflection::GetRepeatedPtrField(
    const Message& message, const FieldDescriptor* field) const {
  return *static_cast<RepeatedPtrField<PB>* >(
      MutableRawRepeatedField(const_cast<Message*>(&message), field,
          FieldDescriptor::CPPTYPE_MESSAGE, -1,
          PB::default_instance().GetDescriptor()));
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**The Correct Answer**

The right answer here is that instead of using `Reflection::GetRepeatedPtrField<T>()`, you should use `Reflection::GetRepeatedMessage()` to get a generic `const Message&` for each element of the repeated field. Unfortunately you will need to call this method once for each element (use `Reflection::FieldSize()` to find the size).

On each `Message`, you can then use `Message::GetDescriptor()`, look up the field named `test_field`, then `Message::GetReflection()` and use that to read the value of that field. As an optimization, you can safely assume that all messages in the same repeated field have the same `Descriptor` and `Reflection` objects, so you only need to get these objects and look up the `FieldDescriptor` once for the whole array.

Something like (not tested):

```
int size = pReflection->FieldSize(*BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField);
Reflection* pInnerReflection = NULL;
FieldDescriptor* pTestFieldDesc = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  const Message& msg = pReflection->GetRepeatedMessage(
      *BATTLE_DATA, pMessageField, i);
  if (pInnerReflection == NULL) {
    pInnerReflection = msg.GetReflection();
    pTestFieldDesc = msg.GetDescriptor()
        ->FindFieldByName("test_field");
  }
  int testField = pInnerReflection->GetInt32(msg, pTestFieldDesc);
  // ...
}
```

**A Fun But Bad Answer**

This second solution will perform slightly better and look a little prettier. Unfortunately, it is *technically* undefined behavior. It will work in practice on all compilers but probably you shouldn't do it unless you have a performance problem. I include it here for fun, and because you'll probably figure it out anyway so it's good to know about why it's bad.

You could call `GetRepeatedPtrField<google::protobuf::Message>(...)` to get a `RepeatedPtrField` of generic `Message` objects. You can then obtain the descriptor and reflection as with the first solution, but you no longer need to call `Reflection::GetMessage` (a virtual call) to read each message. (You do still need to invoke reflection to read `test_field`, though.)

This is technically undefined behavior because it assumes a few things:

- That `RepeatedPtrField<T>` has the same layout for all `T`. This is in fact true because `RepeatedPtrField<T>` extends `RepeatedPtrFieldBase` and does not add any new fields, but the C++ standard doesn't require that this be the case.
- That upcasting a specific message type pointer (like `AInfo*`) to `Message*` does not change the bits of the pointer. In practice, this is true on all compilers as long as no multiple inheritance is in play, and Protobufs does not use multiple inheritance (the Google C++ style guide even prohibits it).
- That the compiler will not optimize based on strict aliasing rules in such a way that it ends up reordering accesses to your `RepeatedPtrField<Message>` vs. other accesses to `RepeatedPtrField<AInfo>` (or whichever type) occurring elsewhere in the program. In practice, it's unreasonable to imagine any compiler actually doing this for this use case, but it's technically allowed by C++.